# Angular - How to get the component instance of the route you've navigated to in an integration test?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, typescript, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I'm writing an integration test for the first time and I'm a bit confused on how to go about it.

Basically what I've done so far is set up the `AppComponent` with a `/signin` route you can go to, this is what I'm testing.

This is my test setup:

```
describe('[INTEGRATION] SigninComponent', () => {

  let component: AppComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;
  let location: Location;
  let router: Router;
  let usernameFormControlElement;
  let passwordFormControlElement;
  let submitBtn;

  beforeEach(() => {

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        AppModule,
        ModuleImports,
        RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([
          {path: 'signin', component: SigninComponent}
        ])
      ],
      providers: [
        Location
      ],
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
      declarations: [SigninComponent]
    });

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    location = TestBed.get(Location);
    router = TestBed.get(Router);

    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should navigate to dashboard when a token is received', async(() => {

    router.navigate(['signin']).then(() => {

      expect(location.path()).toBe('/signin');

      // Get the elements once we're on the right page
      usernameFormControlElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.username')).nativeElement;
      passwordFormControlElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.password')).nativeElement;
      submitBtn = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#submit')).nativeElement;

      // How exactly would I get a hold of the SigninComponent`instance here?
      const signinComponent = 
    });
  }));
});
```

Now, where the `const signinComponent =` statement is, I'm not sure how to proceed. I need to get hold of the `SigninComponent` instance here so that I can get access to the reactive form model and set some values for `username` and `password` form elements and then submit the form.

I don't think I'm supposed to call `TestBed.createComponent(SigninComponent)` and then get the `componentInstance` from that since we've already done that with the `AppComponent`.

What is the correct way of doing this?

**EDIT:**

I figured I could use `ActivatedRoute` but trying to read `.component` on it returns null.